# Disabling hover effect of nav toggle button when nav is open

Tags: javascript, gsap

I'm trying to disable the hover effect of the navigation toggle button when the navigation menu is open. I'm toggling a class when the button is clicked and running an if statement that says it should only run the animation if the class isn't toggled. I can see in the console that div.toggle-btn is toggling the disable-hover class but it doesn't disable/enable the javascript code like I expect.

```js
var btnhover = new TimelineMax({paused: true});

    var navtoggle = $('.toggle-btn').hasClass('disable-hover');

    if (navtoggle === false) {
      if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
        btnhover.to(".one", .3, {
           y: 5,
           ease: Expo.easeInOut,
        })}
      else {
        btnhover.to(".one", .3, {
           x: -5,
           ease: Expo.easeInOut,
        })
      }
    }

    if (navtoggle === false) {
      if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
        btnhover.to(".two", .3, {
           y: -5,
           ease: Expo.easeInOut,
           delay: -.3
        })}
      else {
        btnhover.to(".two", .3, {
           x: 5,
           ease: Expo.easeInOut,
           delay: -.3
        })
      }
    }

    function btnover(){
      if (navtoggle === false) {
        btnhover.play();
      }
    }

    function btnout(){
      if (navtoggle === false) {
        btnhover.reverse();
      }
    }

    $(".toggle-btn").hover(btnover, btnout);


    function disableHover() {
      $("div.toggle-btn").toggleClass("disable-hover");
    }

$(document).on("click", ".toggle-btn", function() {
      disableHover();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are using `navtoggle = false`, which would translate to 'navtoggle equals false', and when you're updating a variable's value, it will always return true.

You want to use `navtoggle === false` or `!navtoggle`, which would translate to 'is navtoggle equal to false?'.

Second, you are also not checking whether the button has the disable class or not inside of the btnover/btnout functions. You should add a conditional inside of those functions to check whether or not the animation should play.

Lastly, you need to actually check whether or not the button has the class on each hover. Once you set the navtoggle variable, it is not going to change again. Check inside of the btnover/btnout functions to see if button has said class.

```
function btnover(){
  var navtoggle = $('.toggle-btn').hasClass('disable-hover');

  if (navtoggle === false) {
    btnhover.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's very true, thank you. However I updated it to triple equals and it still doesn't work. It always triggers the hover animation, even though the class is being toggled.

Comment: I added the same conditional statement to both functions and still the same thing. Animation still runs when class is toggled.

Comment: Sorry man I didn't notice your last edit until now. That did it, thanks so much.